# convert many date formats to its assigned formatted date

Tags: sql-server, regex, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime, sql-timestamp

I want to convert Non-Standard Date Formats to Standard Date format. Table has Column_A and Column_B I have column_A as input and I want the corresponding value on column_B.

[image]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.

Comment: also post your query what you have tried

Comment: sql server 2012

Comment: Oops.. the image is hyperlinked with the question. i wasnt aware

Comment: How do you expect to be able to distinguish between 11/2 and 2/11 (just one example!). Basically, your problem is *exactly* why you store dates in a date/datetime and not as text. And if this is an import, then you need to either have a standardiszed format or include information in the import as to the format of the date. You cant magically know the right format.

Comment: Exactly, that's one of the problem. I would not take the future date. 2017/11/02 will be date format and not 2018/11/02

Comment: As Jamiec said,  Input column  is not a standard insert. in this case you might have to write query for every row

Comment: can it be done through Regex?